# How do I use scp backwards?

Tags: scp

I want to do the following:

```
scp root@server.ip.adress:/root/file.txt ~/homecomputer/directory
```

Instead of taking a file from the server though, I would like to send a file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
scp source destination
```

So this time the source is your local (client) computer and the destination is the remote (server) computer.

If the file you want to send is `~/homecomputer/directory/foobar.txt`, then from your local computer you can do:

```
scp ~/homecomputer/directory/foobar.txt root@server.ip.adress:/where/to/put
```

Check `man scp` to get more idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a file FROM a server TO your local computer, then exactly what you suggested works, IF you run this from your LOCAL computer, NOT your REMOTE server:

`scp root@server.ip.adress:/root/file.txt ~/homecomputer/directory`

Here, `root@server.ip.adress:/root/file.txt` is your `source` and `~/homecomputer/directory` your destination.

NOTE: This answer assumes that you don't need some private key to SSH into your server.